# Invalid agrument error using hyperas in keras

Tags: python, keras

I have been attempting to use the hyperas wrapper to search for optimal hyperparameters. Right now I am keeping it relatively basic to get it working first. Unfortunately, I am getting an "invalid argument" error.  I am working in jupyter notebook.

I have read that I might have to not use jupyter notebook but I would like to continue using it if possible.

```
import keras

# prevents memory allocation errors when using GPU
from keras import backend as K
cfg = K.tf.ConfigProto()
cfg.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
K.set_session(K.tf.Session(config=cfg))

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dropout, Dense, Activation
from keras.regularizers import l2
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization

from keras.optimizers import Adam, sgd
from keras.activations import relu
from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy
from keras import metrics

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# load data
x_main = pd.read_csv("glioma DB X.csv")

y_main = pd.read_csv("glioma DB Y.csv")

# fill with median (will have to improve later, not done yet)
fill_median =['Surgery_SBRT','df','Dose','Ki67','KPS','BMI','tumor_size']

x_main[fill_median] = x_main[fill_median].fillna(x_main[fill_median].median())

x_main['Neurofc'] = x_main['Neurofc'].fillna(2)

x_main['comorbid'] = x_main['comorbid'].fillna(int(x_main['comorbid'].median()))

# drop surgery
x_main = x_main.drop(['Surgery'], axis=1)

# normalize all x

x_main_normalized = x_main.apply(lambda x: (x-np.mean(x))/(np.std(x)+1e-10))

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_main, y_main, test_size=0.3)
x_test, x_val, y_test, y_val = train_test_split(x_test, y_test, test_size=0.5)

params = {'lr': 0.0001,
     'batch_size': 30,
     'epochs': 100,
     'dropout': 0.2,
     'weight_regulizer':['l2'],
     'optimizer': 'sgd',
     'losses': 'categorical_crossentropy',
     'activation':'relu',
     'last_activation': 'softmax'}

from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

#categorical_labels = to_categorical(int_labels, num_classes=None)

last_layer = 1

if params['losses']=='categorical_crossentropy':
    y_train = to_categorical(y_train,num_classes=4)
    y_val = to_categorical(y_val,num_classes=4)
    y_test = to_categorical(y_test,num_classes=4)
    last_layer=4

from hyperopt import Trials, STATUS_OK, tpe

from keras.utils import np_utils

from hyperas import optim
from keras.models import model_from_json

from hyperas.distributions import choice, uniform, conditional

# Data()

def data():
    x_train = x_train
    x_val = x_val
    y_train = y_train
    y_val = y_val
    return x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val

def model(x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val, layers=[20, 20, 4], 
                 kernel_init ='he_uniform', bias_init ='he_uniform',
                 batch_norm=True, dropout=True):

    model = Sequential()

    # layer 1
    model.add(Dense({{choice([10, 20, 30, 50])}},
                    input_dim=x_train.shape[1],
                    W_regularizer=l2(l2_reg),
                    kernel_initializer=kernel_init,
                    bias_initializer=bias_init))

    if batch_norm == True:
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=momentum, center=True))

    model.add(Activation(params['activation']))

    if dropout == True:
        model.add(Dropout({{uniform(0, 0.5)}}))

    # layer 2+    
    for layer in range(0, len(layers)-1):

        model.add(Dense({{choice([10, 20, 30, 50])}}, 
                        W_regularizer=l2(l2_reg),
                        kernel_initializer=kernel_init,
                        bias_initializer=bias_init))

        if batch_norm == True:
            model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=momentum, center=True))

        model.add(Activation(params['activation']))

        if dropout == True:
            model.add(Dropout(params['dropout']))

    # Last layer
    model.add(Dense(layers[-1], activation=params['last_activation'],
                    kernel_initializer=kernel_init,
                    bias_initializer=bias_init))

    model.compile(loss=params['losses'],
                  optimizer=keras.optimizers.adam(lr=params['lr']),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, 
                        validation_data=[x_val, y_val],
                        batch_size={{choice([5, 10, 30, 60])}},
                        epochs=params['epochs'],
                        verbose=1)

    score, acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
    print('Test accuracy:', acc)
    return {'loss': -acc, 'status': STATUS_OK, 'model': model}

    history_dict = history.history

    return {'model':model, 'status': STATUS_OK, 'history_dict':history_dict, 'loss':-acc}


best_run, best_model = optim.minimize(model=model,
                                      data=data,
                                      algo=tpe.suggest,
                                      max_evals=2,
                                      trials=Trials())

x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val = data()
print("Evalutation of best performing model:")
print(best_model.evaluate(x_val, y_val))
print("Best performing model chosen hyper-parameters:")
print(best_run)
```

Error:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-7cf7a7c755ab> in <module>()
     64                                       algo=tpe.suggest,
     65                                       max_evals=2,
---> 66                                       trials=Trials())
     67 
     68 x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val = data()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hyperas\optim.py in minimize(model, data, algo, max_evals, trials, functions, rseed, notebook_name, verbose, eval_space, return_space)
     65                                      full_model_string=None,
     66                                      notebook_name=notebook_name,
---> 67                                      verbose=verbose)
     68 
     69     best_model = None

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hyperas\optim.py in base_minimizer(model, data, functions, algo, max_evals, trials, rseed, full_model_string, notebook_name, verbose, stack)
     94         model_str = full_model_string
     95     else:
---> 96         model_str = get_hyperopt_model_string(model, data, functions, notebook_name, verbose, stack)
     97     temp_file = './temp_model.py'
     98     write_temp_files(model_str, temp_file)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hyperas\optim.py in get_hyperopt_model_string(model, data, functions, notebook_name, verbose, stack)
    176     else:
    177         calling_script_file = os.path.abspath(inspect.stack()[stack][1])
--> 178         with open(calling_script_file, 'r') as f:
    179             source = f.read()
    180 

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\Michael\\Desktop\\CSV data-20180807T164633Z-001\\CSV data\\<ipython-input-7-7cf7a7c755ab>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Jeez I need to read more. I think my question is answered on the github site

```
notebook adjustment
If you find error like "No such file or directory" or OSError, Err22, you may need add notebook_name='simple_notebook'(assume your current notebook name is simple_notebook) in optim.minimize function like this:

best_run, best_model = optim.minimize(model=model,
                                      data=data,
                                      algo=tpe.suggest,
                                      max_evals=5,
                                      trials=Trials(),
                                      notebook_name='simple_notebook')
```

except I needed to put

```
notebook='keras_glioma_hyperopt')
```

the name of my notebook is keras_glioma_hyperopt

Still running into errors but it could be in my set up with my code. I will update as a go along but the above code helped me progressed.

## EDIT

finally got it to run.

Problems I ran into:

1. you really need to put all the data loading into data():
   I changed mine to

   def data():

   ```
   # load data
   x_main = pd.read_csv("glioma DB X.csv")

   y_main = pd.read_csv("glioma DB Y.csv")

   # fill with median (will have to improve later, not done yet)
   fill_median =['Surgery_SBRT','df','Dose','Ki67','KPS','BMI','tumor_size']

   x_main[fill_median] = x_main[fill_median].fillna(x_main[fill_median].median())

   x_main['Neurofc'] = x_main['Neurofc'].fillna(2)

   x_main['comorbid'] = x_main['comorbid'].fillna(int(x_main['comorbid'].median()))

   # drop surgery
   x_main = x_main.drop(['Surgery'], axis=1)

   # normalize all x

   x_main_normalized = x_main.apply(lambda x: (x-np.mean(x))/(np.std(x)+1e-10))

   from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

   x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_main, y_main, test_size=0.3)
   x_test, x_val, y_test, y_val = train_test_split(x_test, y_test, test_size=0.5)

   last_layer = 1

   params = {'lr': 0.0001,
    'batch_size': 30,
    'epochs': 100,
    'dropout': 0.2,
    'weight_regulizer':['l2'],
    'optimizer': 'sgd',
    'losses': 'categorical_crossentropy',
    'activation':'relu',
    'last_activation': 'softmax'}

   from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

   if params['losses']=='categorical_crossentropy':
       y_train = to_categorical(y_train,num_classes=4)
       y_val = to_categorical(y_val,num_classes=4)
       y_test = to_categorical(y_test,num_classes=4)
       last_layer=4

   x_train = x_train
   x_val = x_val
   y_train = y_train
   y_val = y_val



   return x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val
   ```
2. I also ran into the error

   TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable

if you follow the hyperas github the fix is

```
pip install networkx==1.11
```